# Can a DNN user be associated with a Facebook profile?

Tags: facebook, dotnetnuke-5

I would like the users on my DNN website to associate their accounts with their Facebook account. Once this is done, they should be able to login with either the website UN/PW or Facebook.

I currently have Facebook login integrated on the website using a 3rd party module. But the way it works is, that it creates a new user whenever a new profile is used for login. Instead of that, I'd like current users to specify their Facebook profiles in some way and then use it for login if they wish.

I am not sure if this is even possible. Any input appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to check with the creator of the third party module you are using, there isn't anything in DNN specifically to do Facebook logins right now.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't want to use the module specifically - just mentioned it to clarify what we are doing right now. I am not even sure if something like this can be done. The part I have difficulty with is the FB a/c and DNN a/c association. How can that be achieved? I cannot find any unique information of FB a/c that I can store in DNN.